# unexpected result with range in packaging.version.parse in Python

Tags: python, comparison, version, python-packaging

Checking if a version is in range give me an unexpected result:

```
>>> packaging.version.parse('1.2.3') == packaging.version.parse('1.2.*')
False
```

I expected True.
While

```
>>> packaging.version.parse('1.2.3') > packaging.version.parse('1.2.*')
True
```

This is at least unintuitive, right?
Is this a bug or do I miss something?

Comment: That is how I understand the PEP-440: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440
I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use

```
packaging.specifiers.SpecifierSet('==1.2.*').contains(packaging.version.Version('1.2.3'))
```